# Getting the address of a std::vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm using DirectX and I would like to access the vertices std::vector which are defined and assigned inside a struct.

```
struct Mesh
{
 std::<vector> mVertices;
}
```

I would like to get the address of the first element

```
vinitData.pSysMem = m_Mesh.m_Vertices[0];
```

I tried the above line but it doesn't work at all.

The only work  around is I copied the vertices to another std:vector then assign it to pSysMem and that worked.

By doing like that:

```
std::vector<VertexAttribute> vertices(m_Mesh.m_Vertices.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Mesh.m_Vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        vertices[i].Pos = m_Mesh.m_Vertices[i].Position;

    }
```

Comment: *"I tried the above line but it doesn't work at all."* ... does it not compile? Does it throw a run-time error? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Cyber It gives wrong results of the vertices, like corrupted geometry on the screen.

Comment: What is the declared type of `mVertices` in your code? It can't be `std::<vector>`, because that wouldn't compile. I suspect this is a critical part of the problem. The fact that `vertices[i]` has a `Pos` field but `m_Mesh.m_Vertices[i]` has a `Position` field is worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either get it by stating:

```
vinitData.pSysMem = &(m_Mesh.m_Vertices[0]);
```

or if your compiler supports C++11:

```
vinitData.pSysMem = const_cast<Vertix*>(m_Mesh.m_Vertices.data());
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` returns reference, not pointer.
Use:

```
vinitData.pSysMem = &m_Mesh.m_Vertices[0];
```

BTW, i am assuming you use `std::vector<Vertix>`